# Using the input of inputbox in msgbox prompt

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making an InputBox so the user can put his/her name to be used for the MsgBox. Instead of "hello user", it would be "hello (name)". This was my attempt.

```
Private Username As String
Username = InputBox(msg, "dear user")
InputBox msg, "dear user"
If Username = vbNullString Then
    Username = InputBox(msg, "dear user")
End If
```

I tried first making the inputbox (which is working).

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_open()

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select

    Dim msg
    msg = "Please enter your name here"
    InputBox msg, "dear user"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret As Variant

    Ret = InputBox("Please enter your name", "dear user")

    If Len(Trim(Ret)) <> 0 Then MsgBox "Hello " & Ret
End Sub
```

> I tried using urcode, but it doesnt seem to work? i tried placing it in the sheet, module, & workbook but nothing is happening D: and oh yea, my aim is to use the input of the inputbox for all the msgboxes im going to use in all my sheets, say first, if the file opens, it asks for the name of the user; after typing the name, there is a msgbox saying "welcome to the game"(or something like that) then there are different sheets for my games like roll the dice, maze, etc. so when the user goes to the sheet, it welcomes them again via msgbox and congratulates them when the game has been finished – Kurt Cinco 31 mins ago

In such a case you should not use a public variable. The variable resets when there is an error. I would recommend saving that name to a cell in a hidden sheet.

**A**. Add a sheet call say `Settings`. Hide the sheet.

**B**. In the workbook open, paste this code

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim Ret As Variant

    Ret = InputBox("Please enter your name", "dear user")

    If Len(Trim(Ret)) <> 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Range("A1").Value = Ret
        MsgBox "welcome to the game " & Ret
    End If
End Sub
```

**C**: In the sheet code are you can use this code

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim username As String

    username = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Settings").Range("A1").Value

    MsgBox "Hello " & username
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried using urcode, but it doesnt seem to work? i tried placing it in the sheet, module, & workbook but nothing is happening D: and oh yea, my aim is to use the input of the inputbox for all the msgboxes im going to use in all my sheets, say first, if the file opens, it asks for the name of the user; after typing the name, there is a msgbox saying "welcome to the game"(or something like that) then there are different sheets for my games like roll the dice, maze, etc. so when the user goes to the sheet, it welcomes them again via msgbox and congratulates them when the game has been finished

Comment: One moment. Updating the post

Answer (score 0):

you can set a `ThisWorkbook` object property

place this code in `ThisWorkbook` code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Private mUserName As String

Sub Workbook_Open()
    mUserName = InputBox("Please enter your name", "dear user")
End Sub

Public Property Get MyUserName() As String
    MyUserName = mUserName
End Property
```

now you can access from any plain module and/or sheet module by simply coding

```
MsgBox "hello " & ThisWorkbook.MyUserName
```

---

as a possible enhancement, you could force the user to put some valid name by properly tweaking `Workbook_Open()` sub, like:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
    Do
         mUserName = InputBox("Please enter your name", "dear user")
    Loop While mUserName = vbNullString
End Sub
```